# implementing class iterator that iterates over a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory-leaks, iterator

how can i create a class iterator that iterates over a generic map nodes without causing memory leaks?
my map has a class that's called "pair" which is generic and has a value and a key.
also a class that's called node that contains a pair and pointers to the next node and previous nodes.
the map itself contains the head node. and the map size ..
this code work,my problem is that it has memory leaks.
since the iterator is a class (we were asked to implemented as a class not only a node) and it contains a pointer to a Node which has a pair. we can't delete the pair by deleting the node whenever we want to use the iterator destructor cause that deletes completely the pair and the node causing elements loss in the map.
can you give some advice how to implemented correctly without memory leaks? 
and very important : the map function end() should return a random value that is not one of the map elements (that's why i set it to be NULL)

```
template <class KeyType, class ValueType, class CompareFunction = std::less<KeyType> >
class MtmMap {
public:

    class Pair {
    public:
        Pair(const KeyType& key, const ValueType& value)
            : first(key), second(value) {}
        Pair()
            : first(NULL), second(NULL) {}
        ~Pair(){}
        const KeyType first;
        ValueType second;
        bool operator==(const Pair& pair)const{
            if(pair.first==this->first&&pair.second==this->second){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const Pair& pair)const{
            if(this==pair){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        Pair& operator=(const Pair& pair){
            if(this==&pair){
                return *this;
            }
            this->first=pair.first;
            this->second=pair.second;
            return *this;
        }
        Pair& operator=(ValueType val){
            this->second=val;
            return *this;
        }
        const KeyType& getFirst(){
            KeyType* keyPointer=&first;
            return (first);
        }
        ValueType getSecond(){
            ValueType* valPoiner= &second;
            return (valPoiner);
        }
    };

    class Node {
        public:
            Pair* element;
            //int plc;
            Node* next;
            Node* before;
            Node() :element(), next(NULL),before(NULL){}

            Node(const Node& copyNode) :
                    element(new Pair(*(copyNode.element))), next(
                            copyNode.next) ,before(copyNode.before){
            }
            Node& operator++(){
                if(this->next){
                return(this->next);
                }
                Node* node=new Node;
                node->next=NULL;
                node->element=NULL;
                //node->first=NULL;
                return(node);
            }
            Node operator++(int n){
                Node result=*this;
                ++this;
                return result;
            }
            Node& operator--(){
                return(this->before);
            }
            bool operator==(const Node& node)const{
                if(node.before==this->before&&node.element==this->element&&node.next==this->next){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            bool operator!=(const Node& node)const{
            if(this==node){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            }
            Node& operator=(const Node& node){
                if(this==&node){
                    return *this;
                }
                this->before=node.before;
                this->element=node.element;
                this->next=node.next;
                return *this;
            }

            }

        };

    class iterator{
    public:
        Node* p;
        iterator():p(){}
        iterator(const iterator& it):p(it.p){}
        ~iterator(){
        }
        iterator& operator++(){
        this->p=this->p->next;
        if(this->p){
            return *this;
        }
        this->p=NULL;
        return *this;
        }
        iterator operator++(int n){
            iterator result=*this;
            ++*this;
            return result;
        }
        iterator& operator=(const iterator& it){
            if(this==&it){
                return *this;
            }
            this->p=it.p;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator==(const iterator& iterator)const{
            if(this->p==iterator.p){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const iterator& iterator)const{
            if(this->p!=iterator.p){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        const Pair& operator*(){
            if(*this==end()){
                throw MapElementNotFoundException();
            }
            return *p->element;
        }
        iterator& begin(){
            while(p->before!=NULL){
                p--;
            }
            return *this;
        }
        iterator& end(){
            iterator* it=new iterator();
            it->p=NULL;
            return *it;

        }



    };

    int mapSize;
    Node* head;
    iterator iter;
    ValueType initializer;
    CompareFunction compareFunc;

    MtmMap(ValueType val):mapSize(0),head(),iter(),initializer(val){}
```

Comment: Perhaps because the directory names don't match what you say they are?

Comment: you stated the executables were to be in the top directory, then generated them in sub directories and did not copy them to the top directory.

Comment: regarding this line: `DEBUG_FLAG   := -L. -lmtm`   This says there are one (or more) libraries in the 'main' directory.  But your question fails to disclose that critical detail

Comment: the `-DNDEBUG` is normally part of the compile rules, not the linker rules

Comment: there are several header files involved, but your question fails to specify exactly where each header file is located.  I made some guesses in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a relative path that accurately reflects your directory structure. Example:

```
include my_set/Makefile
include tests/Makefile

# ...

TEST_OBJS1 = tests/cache_test.o cache.o 
TEST_OBJS2 = tests/memcache_test.o memcache.o cache.o user.o
TEST_OBJS3 = my_set/my_set_test.o my_set/my_set.o

# ...
```

Basically, you'll want to create a "Makefile" in each subdirectory that you "include" and that defines the rules for building each of the targets in those subdirectories (and using the paths relative to the root Makefile directory in the rules), and in your top-level Makefile, you will similarly refer to those files / targets by their paths relative to the top-level Makefile directory (rather than by filename).

Comment: i tried that, not i'm getting an error : undefined reference to all the functions . because the header  and the c files are in the main directory and the test is in the sub dir.

Comment: i want the exec files to be generated in the main directory

Comment: @RawanShu If this answer helped (by moving you forward even if you still have an error) then you should accept it. If you still have other issues you can create a new question to get the new issue solved. (Your errors are likely because your compilation commands are not properly passing the necessary directories to the header files, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

given the directory layout of:

```
main/
    cache.c
    cache.h
    memcache.c
    memcache.h
    user.c
    user.h
    my_set/
        my_set.c
        my_set.h
        my_set_test.c
    tests/
        memcache_test.c
        cache_test.c
```

when defining a macro, if it will only be evaluated once, use `:=` rather than `=`

when giving a macro name to a external executable, always supply the full path

Note: the answer contains spaces at the beginning of the make rule commands
which have to be replaced with tab to implement the makefile syntax

The question fails to specify the location of certain header files and fails to indicate which header files are used by certain .c files.

The assumption is that all header files not specifically located in the directory layout are actually in the 'main/' directory.

Those explicit compile rules were the header file dependencies are not known have this text `??? which header files ???`

The proposed makefile contents follows:

```
#CC=gcc
CC := /usr/bin/gcc
RM := /usr/bin/rm

# you stated the executables were to be in the main directory
#EXEC1 = /tests/cache_test
#EXEC2 = /tests/memcache_test
#EXEC3 = /my_set/my_set_test
EXEC1 := cache_test
EXEC2 := memcache_test
EXEC3 := my_set_test

# when object in sub directory, include the directory path
TEST_OBJS1 := tests/cache_test.o cache.o
TEST_OBJS2 := tests/memcache_test.o memcache.o cache.o user.o
TEST_OBJS3 := my_set/my_set_test.o my_set/my_set.o

LIBS         := -L. -lmtm
DNDEBUG_FLAG := -DNDEBUG

CFLAGS := -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -std=c99 -g

# need to tell ''make'' that certain targets do not produce a output file
.PHONY : all clean

# first/default target in makefile
# it has dependencies on each of the 3 executables
#   so, by default, the three executables will be generated
all: $(EXEC1) $(EXEC2) $(EXEC3)
        @echo "all done"

# link rules needs any 'special' library path and library name parameters
$(EXEC2): $(TEST_OBJS2)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) $(TEST_OBJS2) -o  $@  $(LIBS)

$(EXEC1): $(TEST_OBJS1)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) $(TEST_OBJS1) -o  $@  $(LIBS)

$(EXEC3): $(TEST_OBJS3)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) $(TEST_OBJS3) -o  $@  $(LIBS)


# compile rules have no use for library path and library name parameters
#     they do have use for where to find the user supplied header files
#     especially if those header files are not in the current directory

# only compile one file in each explicit compile rule

# always place the source file name as the first dependency parameter
#      so '$<' can be used to reference it

cache.o: cache.c cache.h list.h set.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I.

user.o: user.c user.h set.h list.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I.

memcache.o: memcache.c cache.h list.h set.h user.h memcache.h map.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I.

my_set/my_set.o: my_set/my_set.c my_set/my_set.h list.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I. -Imy_set/.

tests/cache_test.o : tests/cache_test.c ??? which header files ???
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I. -Itests/.

tests/memcache_test.o : tests/memcache_test.c ??? which header files ???
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I. -Itests/.

my_set/my_set_test.o : my_set/my_set_test.c ??? which header files ???
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(DNDEBUG_FLAG) -c $< -o $@  -I. -Imy_set/.


# all three directories need to be cleaned
# the ( cd .... && .... ) lines
# start a new sub shell, 
# cd to the appropriate directory, 
# perform the rm function, 
# and exit the sub shell
# which results in being back in the original directory
clean:
        $(RM) -f *.o $(EXEC1) $(EXEC2) #(EXEC3)
        ( cd my_set && $(RM) -f *.o )
        ( cd tests  && $(RM) -f *.o )
```